# openpyxl Check if row contains two cells of seperate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I can iterate through cells in rows to check for cells containing a certain value. Now I'm trying to check if the row also contains second value.

```
target = input("Input cell value: ")
target2 = input("Input second cell value ")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == target: 
            # I'd also like to check if row contains second target
                print(cell.value)
```

Comment: Where is the second value? The check will be the same.

Comment: I want to make sure the second value is on the same row as the first value. So check if a row contains two cells of different values

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I really understand the question but the best way to approach this is to use sets to compare all values at once.

```
targets = {target, target2}
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(values_only=True),1):
    if set(row) & targets:
        print(f"Row {idx} contains all the values")
```